# How to groupby a dataframe excluding dome rows

Tags: julia

I am working on a groupby operation using the `attribute` column but I want to exclude the `desc_type 1 and 2` that will be used to calculate total discount inside each attrib.

dataframe:

```
ID       attribute       value      discount
10       attrib_1        100          0
10       desc_type1       0           6
10       desc_type2       0           2
20       attrib_1         100         0
30       attrib_2         30          0
30       desc_type1       0           13.3
```

I want to groupby this dataframe by `attribute` but excluding the `desc_type1 and desc_type2`.

The desired output:

```
attribute     ID_count    value_sum   discount_sum
attrib_1         2          200          8
attrib_2         1          30          13.3
```

explanations:

`attrib_1` has **discount_sum=8**  because **ID 30** that belongs to `attrib_1`has two desc_type

`attrib_2` has **discount_sum=13.3**  because **ID 10** has one desc_type

`ID=20` has no discounts types.

Important:  an ID may have a discount or not.

link to the realdataset: [realdataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13i3ArvBXj2VBRhquAvoUX5H7puFRODNy/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106219169070264712406&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your task is that for a single `:ID` there are multiple `"VLR"` entries sometimes. In the code below I assume that these discounts then apply to all of them (assume that `df` is a source data frame):

```
gdf = groupby(df, :ID)
function process_group(sdf)
    rows = findall(startswith("VLR"), sdf.atributte)
    (atributte = sdf[rows, :atributte],
     value = sdf.value[rows],
     discount = fill(sum(sdf.discount[Not(rows)]), length(rows))) # here I assume discounts apply the same to all VLSs in the group
end
res1 = combine(gdf, process_group)
gdf2 = groupby(res1, :atributte)
final_res = combine(gdf2, nrow => :ID_count, [:value, :discount] .=> sum)
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks Bogumil Kaminski

Answer (score 1):

The following script gives what I think you would want and not exactly what the question explained.

```
using CSV, DataFrames

df2 = CSV.read("realdata.xlsx - Sheet1.csv", DataFrame)

df3 = select(df2, 
    Not([:Column1, :atributte]),
    :atributte => :attribute, 
    :value .=> (x -> parse.(Float64, replace.(x, ',' => '.'))) .=> :value, 
    :discount .=> (x-> parse.(Float64, replace.(x, ','=>'.'))) .=> :discount
)

unstack(
  combine(
    groupby(
      stack(df3, [:value, :discount], Not([:value, :discount])
    ), 
    [:ID, :variable]),
    :value .=> sum .=> :value,
    :attribute .=> (x->x[findfirst(x->startswith(x,"VLR"),x)]) .=> :attribute
  ),
  [:ID, :attribute], 
  :variable, 
  :value
)
```

The output of the above is:

```
285×4 DataFrame
 Row │ ID        attribute                          value     discount 
     │ String15  String                             Float64?  Float64? 
─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 04135-17  VLR MENSAL ACESSO NÃO REDUNDANTE…    530.12      6.6
   2 │ 04136-17  VLR MENSAL ACESSO NÃO REDUNDANTE…    530.12      6.6
   3 │ 04140-17  VLR MENSAL ACESSO NÃO REDUNDANTE…    660.38      8.22
:
:
```

or on the simple example in the question:

```
3×4 DataFrame
 Row │ ID     attribute  value     discount 
     │ Int64  String15   Float64?  Float64? 
─────┼──────────────────────────────────────
   1 │    10  attrib_1      100.0       8.0
   2 │    20  attrib_1      100.0       0.0
   3 │    30  attrib_2       30.0      13.3
```

To get the summary by `attribute` values (or VLRs) another `groupby` is needed, but it may be the case same VLR may receive different discounts, in which case the table has the information to calculate the summary properly.

Comment: Thanks Dan Getz.  But the output of your asnwer is not what I am looking for. Huge thanks tho.